# Angular - call setters/getters in html

Tags: html, angular, getter-setter

I have in the .ts file the following code:

```
  set query(query: string) {
    this.form.get('query').setValue(query);
  }

  get query() {
    return this.form.controls.query;
  }
```

I am trying to call the getter method in .html file as:

```
  <div *ngIf="!query.valid && (query?.dirty || query?.touched)">
      <div [hidden]="!query.errors.required">Query is required</div>
    </div>
```

However, an error is thrown. The code works perfectly if I remove the setter from the .ts file.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Could you please provide us with the error that is being thrown?

Comment: @LeonardoFreire 
Property 'valid' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: Issue may be caused by your naming: both method and param of your setter are called `query`. Try to change one of them.

Comment: try this
get query(): any {
    return this.form.controls.query;
  }

Comment: @DeepakJha that worked! Thank you very much! :)
* (Could you also explain me, why that conflict happened before? )

Comment: sure let me write that as an answer, may be useful for others too

Comment: dont forget to accept it as an answer so that others can see it too in their google search :)

Comment: @Katherine please see the answer I posted below. It makes for a better solution in terms of Typescript. We don't want Typescript to become Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via two ways,

Way 1:

```
  set query(query: any) {
    this.form.get('query').setValue(query);
  }

  get query() {
    return this.form.controls.query;
  }
```

Way 2:

```
  set query(query: string) {
    this.form.get('query').setValue(query);
  }

  get query(): AbstractControl {
    return this.form.controls.query;
  }
```

when you assign a value to `query`  you are assigning it as a string see the incoming argument type in your setter. So by default angular understands it as string type. Then in your HTML, you try to access it as an object which creates a problem for angular as it expects it to be a string but used as an object.

Comment: Please don't use any when you know what type you're returning. That's missing completely the point of using Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

try form.getControls['query'].setValue(myValue)

form.get('fieldName') will get value of that field ...
form.controls['fieldName'] would get the field itself .. Field control will expose get or set value methods

Answer (score -1):

Although the accepted answer works and the thinking behind it make sense, I would completely avoid using *any* as a return type, when you know exactly what you're returning.

That just goes against the purpose of using Typescript as a language. Using *any* is the same as saying **"accept everything and don't just interpret it as a string"**.

```
set query(query: string) {
    this.form.get('query').setValue(query);
}

get query(): AbstractControl {
    return this.form.controls.query;
}
```

Since you know you're returning an **AbstractControl**, I would set the return type to either *AbstractControl* or, if you want to be more specific, to *FormControl*.

Comment: I can only guess why you've been downvoted but my guess is that typing information, code style etc. is beside the scope of the question. You left a comment under the accepted answer and that is fine.